# KeyError: ('Col_2', 'Col_3') The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Tags: scikit-learn

Could anyone help me debug this error? I appreciate it!

```
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0      8      0      0
1      0      1      0
2      0      0      1
3      8      0      0 



'''
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import sklearn
    from sklearn import  linear_model
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    data = pd.read_csv("simple_data_2.csv")
    print(data.shape)
    data.dropna()
    data = data[["Col_1","Col_2","Col_3"]]
    predict ="Col_1"
    gene1 = "Col_2"
    gene2  = "Col_3"
    data = data.dropna()
    data  =  data.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(data)
    x = np.array(data[gene1,gene2])
    y = np.array(data[predict])
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.1)
    linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    linear.fit(x_train,y_train)
    acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
    print(acc)'''
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Chris/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: ('Col_2', 'Col_3')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/TensorEnv/debug.py", line 16, in 
x = np.array(data[gene1,gene2])
File "/Users/Chris/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "/Users/Chris/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: ('Col_2', 'Col_3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is when you assigned names gene1 and gene2 to columns, you didn't do it properly.

```
gene1 = df["Col_2"]
```

But I wouldn't even bother with that, just use actual column names when feeding data into the algorithm or change their names, you will confuse yourself.

Comment: I used this code before but it didn't work. I got the same error.
x = np.array(data["Col_2","Col_3"])

Comment: you need double brackets for that. x = np.array(data[["Col_2","Col_3"]]). The error that you're getting means that sklearn is having trouble finding those arrays, its a formatting issue